# How to prevent bootstrap from interfering with theme

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a WP plugin that uses bootstrap. However, it seems to be having a very strange affect on the page. You can see it here:

[My Test Page](http://wordpress.kleelof.com/_3_8_0/rentals/)

If you go to this page, then go to another, you will see that the page goes back to normal.

How can I prevent bootstrap from affecting the WP elements on the page?

Comment: you cant if it is enqueued the page. All you can do is change the css vals in your theme (its loaded after plugins) using resets to achieve the look you want. My advice would be to unenqueue bootstrap all together from your theme function file - the page is minimalist and you should be able to recreate easily without BS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer David. But I'm not completely clear on what you mean beginning with 'My advice would be.....'. Are you suggesting loading the Bootstrap files directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_css', 150 );

function bootstrap_css(){

    // add pages for bootstrap leave out site address, just the path e.g. 
    $pages= array( '_3_8_0/rentals/','add_page_url' );
    $path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if( !in_array($path, $pages) ):
        wp_dequeue_style( 'bootstrap_handle' ); // look up handle for stylesheet 
    endif;
}
```

You can do something like the above to de_queue the bootstrap css on pages that you dont want it on. The problem is Bootstrap is not really designed for singular page use with a existing theme and will share a lot of common identifers with what your theme uses e.g. "content"

its either that or remove bootstrap altogether (just de-queue it) and style the page yourself. To be honest bootstrap is a heavy load for the use case here.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I was trying to take the easy way on making the thing responsive. Suppose it's time to learn how to do it for real.